# Telerik Script Registrar Error After Upgrading to ASP.NET MVC 4 Developer Preview

Tags: razor, telerik-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I recently installed the **ASP.NET MVC 4 Developer Preview** (which Microsoft says can be run side by side with other projects written in MVC 3 and not affect them).

When I proceeded to run a MVC 3 application which uses the **Telerik MVC Extensions** (version 2011.3.1115.340) I received an error with the razor engine:

**Compilation Error**

**Description**: *An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.*

**Compiler Error Message**: *CS1593: Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 1 arguments*

Here is the razor source code:

```
@{ Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().OnDocumentReady(
    @<text>    
    $('a[title]').poshytip({
        className: 'tip-yellowsimple',
        alignTo: 'target',
        alignX: 'center',
        alignY: 'bottom',
        offsetY: 5,
        slide: false,
        showTimeout: 0
    });
    </text>);
```

How can I resolve this?

**Resolution Update**

The following info from the [release notes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes) worked for me:

> Installing ASP.NET MVC 4 Developer Preview breaks ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM
>   applications. ASP.NET MVC 3 applications that were created with the
>   RTM release (not with the ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update release) require
>   the following changes in order to work side-by-side with ASP.NET MVC 4
>   Developer Preview. Building the project without making these updates
>   results in compilation errors. Required updates In the root Web.config
>   file, add a new  entry with the key webPages:Version and
>   the value 1.0.0.0. 
>       
>       
>         In Solution Explorer, right-click the project name and
>   then select Unload Project. Then right-click the name again and select
>   Edit ProjectName.csproj. Locate the following assembly references:
>      Replace them with the following:
>      Save
>   the changes, close the project (.csproj) file you were editing, and
>   then right-click the project and select Reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is related to ASP.NET MVC 4 developer preview.

Take a look at the [ASP.NET MVC 4 Release notes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes), specifically the section below:

> Installing ASP.NET MVC 4 Developer Preview breaks ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM applications